# value not getting posted from the element generated by ajax class

Tags: php, ajax, select

This is the HTML form

```
echo "<tr><td>Course</td><td><select name='Course' onchange='branch_selector(this.value)'>";
            echo "<option value='B.Tech'>B.Tech</option>";
            echo "<option value='M.Tech'>M.Tech</option>";
            echo "<option value='MBA'>MBA</option>";
            echo "<option value='MCA'>MCA</option>";
            echo "</select></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td><div id='branch_div_name'></div></td><td><div id='branch_div'></div></td></tr>";
```

this is the javascript code

```
function branch_selector(val) {
    if(val=='B.Tech' || val=='M.Tech') {
        show_name('branch_div_name','Branch');
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }

        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById('branch_div').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }


        }       
        xmlhttp.open("GET","branch_selector.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("branch_div").innerHTML="";
        disappear_name('branch_div_name');
    }
}
```

This is the PHP code running at the backened

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT Branch FROM student_main ORDER BY Branch ASC") or die(mysql_error());
echo "<select name='Branch' id='Branch' onchange='harb()'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($row[0]=='' or $row[0]=='N/A') {
        continue;
    }
    else {
    echo "<option value='".$row[0]."'>".$row[0]."</option>";
}
}

echo "</select>";
```

The dropdown is generated without any problem. But when the form is submitted the $_POST['Branch'] is not set.
Please help

Comment: What does the markup generated by the code look like?  Is the `<select>` contained within the `<form>`?

Comment: yes it is the <select> contained within the <form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have solved this issue, The solution is not the best but its getting the job done.
I am using now a hidden field and the value is this field is set according to the value of Branch of. The value is set using Javascript when user click on submit.
Its working fine, no issue whatsoever but if someone have better solution, please share.